# Regarding Sharing and Updating Shared Folders on Skydrive (Programmatically)

Tags: windows-phone-7, live, onedrive

I have a query regarding accessing Skydrive folders programmatically through the Live SDK on Windows Phone.

So the scenario I have at hand is that a Windows phone app that I have built creates folders (and files) on your Skydrive. Now I want the following functionality which I haven’t been able to do so till now.

Is it possible that I can programmatically share my folder and files with View (and/or edit) permissions to my friends (as I know their user ID)?

If I am able to share such a folder can I access the content after logging in (with my live ID) from my phone. By accessing I mean download or stream content.

If in step 1, a person to whom the file is shared is provided edit permissions how can I programmatically edit such a file?  The current problem I am facing in this step is that to update a shared folder the live sdk requests a wl.contacts_skydrive_update scope, but while logging in I am notified that no such scope exists.

This is the Error message I get when I try to get a shared_edit_link:

> request_token_unauthorized: Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectException: The
>   provided access token does not have access to this resource. An access
>   token with one of the following scopes is required:
>   'wl.contacts_skydrive_update'.

Although the user does have edit permissions. Note: Such a scope doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread on this where it was listed as a bug in the beta. They said that now it should be fixed and you should only need this scope: 'wl.contacts_skydrive'.

[here is the thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/messengerconnect/thread/216aca24-a6e9-4a1b-a52f-dca80d39dcbc)

Comment: I had already had a look at the above mentioned thread but that still seems to be the problem.